# Python: define arguments of a function which include the arguments of the other function

Tags: python, function, arguments

Please let me know if there are duplicated ones (I believe there are) and I will remove the post. I am just not sure about the jargon for this question.

When writing a new function `augmented_func` which contains the other function already defined `original_func`, I am trying to avoid defining arguments that are already in `original_func`:

```
def original_func(a1, a2 ,a3):
    print(a1, a2, a3)

def augmented_func(b, a1, a2, a3):
    print(original_func(a1, a2, a3), b)
```

How do I avoid writing `a`'s when defining `augmented_func`, and make it simpler especially when the number of arguments for `original_func` is more than, say, three in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `*` notation for an arbitrary number of positional arguments:

```
def augmented_func(b, *args):
    print(original_func(*args), b)

augmented_func('b', 1, 2, 3)
```

Or use keyword arguments with `**`:

```
def augmented_func(b, **kwargs):
    print(original_func(**kwargs), b)

augmented_func('b', a1=1, a2=2, a3=3)
```

Comment: oh, so I can just call `augmented_func` as: `augmented_func(b, a1=3, a2=2, a3=4)`, is it correct?

Comment: to do that you would want to use `kwargs`. With `args` you have to pay attention to the order in which you send arguments in.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you looking for is something like

```
def original_func(a1, a2 ,a3):
    print(a1, a2, a3)

def augmented_func(b, *args):
    print(original_func(*args), b)
```

you can call it then as `augmented_func(1, 2, 3, 4)`

`*args` and `**kwargs` is a good way for passing the variable number of arguments and passing them to other internal function calls.

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) for further info.

Comment: Can you also mention how to use kwargs here?